# What is com.onlineapplicationrequest.AppRequest?

Tags: launchd, malware

Along the same lines as [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291367), I've found a user agent I don't recognize on my system.  The label is com.onlineapplicationrequest.AppRequest, and the command it's running is:

> "/Users/jstrout/Library/Application Support/AppCommon/AppRequest"
>   --protect

The ~/Library/Application Support/AppCommon directory looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x   11 jstrout  staff      374 Dec 27  2016 .
drwxrwxrwx  195 jstrout  staff     6630 Apr 11 09:33 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 jstrout  staff       37 Mar  8  2015 .cid
-rw-r--r--    1 jstrout  staff        6 Jan  7  2016 .cnid
-rw-r--r--    1 jstrout  staff       10 Aug 24  2016 .idate
-rw-r--r--    1 jstrout  staff       37 Mar  8  2015 .isn
-rw-r--r--    1 jstrout  staff        0 Dec 15  2016 .upgrade-ff-1.52.4
-rw-r--r--    1 jstrout  staff        0 Dec 27  2016 .upgrade-ff-1.54.2
-rw-r--r--    1 jstrout  staff        0 Dec 15  2016 .upgrade-gc-1.52.4
-rw-r--r--    1 jstrout  staff        0 Dec 27  2016 .upgrade-gc-1.54.2
-rwxr-xr-x    1 jstrout  wheel  1240620 Dec 27  2016 AppRequest
```

Again, the googles have completely failed me on this one.  http://onlineapplicationrequest.com/ exists but appears unused.  Is this more malware?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7602766?start=0&tstart=0 should help

Answer (score 1):

Oops -- I posted too soon.  I have since run Malwarebytes Anti-Malware (thanks to a suggestion on my other post), and this file is identified as an instance of "Adware.Spigot".

I've been laboring under the belief that, as a Mac user who avoids the shady back alleys of the internet, I didn't have to worry about malware.  But apparently that's not quite true!